# How to find opposite of nil in Rails queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid

Happily using `Mongoid` and `ActiveRecord` like this:

```
Task.where(project_id: params[:project_id], archived_at: nil)
# find me the tasks for project_id that haven't been archived
```

But what's a straightforward way for saying the opposite?

```
# find me the tasks for project_id that have been archived
# i.e. where archived_at is not nil
```

Can't figure out or find out the inverse of the first line of code.
I assume it should be straightforward :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use this:

```
:archived_at.ne => nil
```

Take a look at here: [MongoId-Matchers-NE](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Matchers/Ne)